# PHP upload in database and folder in my root folder

Tags: php, image, mysqli, upload

So I'm trying to upload the file name of the image in the database and the image itself will be save in the folder inside a root folder.

In my codes, the image name is able to be saved in the database but the image itself did not save in the folder. Why is that?

Here's my code:

```
<?php

include '../session.php';
require_once 'config.php';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $img_dir = "updated_photo/";
    $target_file = $img_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    $imageType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];

        if (substr($imageType, 0,5) == "image") {
            $query = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `image_name` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $imageName, $_POST['id']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $id = $_POST['id'];

            header("Location: ../admin/view_all_info.php?id=$id");

        }

        else {

            echo "Image not Uploaded!";

        }

}

?>
```

What seems to be the problem of my codes?

Comment: well... you  do not copy this image to folder so why you are surprised?

Comment: You need to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this, I edited your codes.

```
<?php

include '../session.php';
require_once 'config.php';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $img_dir = "../updated_photo/";
    $target_file = $img_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    $imageType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];

        if (substr($imageType, 0,5) == "image") {
            $query = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `image_name` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $imageName, $_POST['id']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            file_put_contents($target_file, $imageData);
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            header("Location: ../admin/view_all_info.php?id=$id");

        }

        else {

            echo "Image not Uploaded!";

        }

}

?>
```

just copy and paste it. tell if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You just get the contain of file. forget to put in target folder use `file_put_contents`

```
 $target_file = $img_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
 $imageName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
 $imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($target_file, $imageData);
```

You can also use **[move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)** to uploaded file to a new location

Comment: i'm still trying to solve it. i will update you if the code worked

Comment: Please verify your path!! what is the value of `echo $target_file`. Check your path is correct or not!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

include '../session.php';
require_once 'config.php';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $img_dir = "updated_photo/";
    $target_file = $img_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    $imageType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];

        if (substr($imageType, 0,5) == "image") {
            $query = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `image_name` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $imageName, $_POST['id']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            //remove
     if (file_exists($target_file))
    {
        $result = unlink($target_file);
        if (!$result)
        {
            //error, display error, 
            return false;
        }
    }
            //upload
             $result  =  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $img_dir);

                if(!$result) 
                    {
                    //error upload
                     }

            header("Location: ../admin/view_all_info.php?id=$id");

        }

        else {

            echo "Image not Uploaded!";

        }

}

?>
```

try